# CallContext.getdata return null

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I used CallContext to store data at service layer. It works well in aspx page. However, it return null in asmx web service. I tried HttpContext.Current.Items[]. Both two pages are working well. My question why CallContext dose not work for asmx web service? Dose I miss something?

Comment: Data put in to `CallContext` or `HttpContext` will work on current request only. So perhaps you should elaborate as to what stage exactly you are storing & retrieving the data (stage in ASP.NET pipeline - which events etc)? Post the relevant code.

Comment: yes, I elaborate on the asp page and web service again and find the reason. In asp page, where is a base page which implement a CallContext.SetData() at the ahead of invoking service method. However, there is no base web service for web service so no object is set into CallContext.